# Adverb placement "which unfortunately I.."

Tags: adverbs

> I have read Book ABC and a few pages of Book XYZ, which unfortunately
>   I left abruptly/ which I unfortunately left abruptly.

Which one is correct? If both are correct, which one to use when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your suggestions are fine, adverb placement is rather fluid in English (usually, look at the adverb "only" which is a major exception and placement definitely matters). However I think the sentence is a bit awkward overall. I would divide it into two thoughts.

"I have read book ABC and a few pages of book XYZ. Unfortunately, I had to leave book XYZ abruptly."

Or if you truly wish to have one sentence, perhaps, "I have read book ABC and a few pages of book XYZ, but unfortunately I had to leave the latter abruptly."

This change of tense sounds better to my ear, but again your sentence works and the adverb position doesn't alter the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The first is definitely better.  "unfortunately" in this case acts as a *sentence adverb* (for the clause "unfortunately I left abruptly").

The second is not incorrect though.

However, in AmE, one does not "leave" reading a book, one "leaves off" reading at some point.  So,

- "...which, unfortunately, I left off [reading] abruptly."